# ¿Cómo poner en un gráfico de seaborn la distribución de la variable tanto en barras como en una línea?

Tags: python, seaborn, visualización-de-datos

Estoy intentando unir en un mismo gráfico la distribución de una variable en forma de barras y también su función de densidad. En definitiva, he logrado mostrar los dos gráficos por separado pero no consigo unirlos. Concretamente, estoy usando un dataset disponible en kaggle ([el de Titanic](https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/data)) y quiero graficar la distribución de la edad, que es una columna del dataset que he llamado `train_data`

```
sns.displot(data=train_data['Age'], kind = ('hist'))
sns.displot(data=train_data['Age'], kind = ('kde'))
```

Esto me devuelve los siguientes gráficos:

[image: Captura1] [image: Captura2]

Lo más parecido que he encontrado es superponer los dos gráficos, tal y como recomiendan en esta otra pregunta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36362624/how-to-plot-multiple-histograms-on-same-plot-with-seaborn

Comment: Te recomiendo que agregues un link al dataset directo, esto para facilitar el trabajar con la misma información que tu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una de las ventajas de trabajar con `displot` de `seaborn` es justamente las diferentes formas de visualización que se tienen de los datos, te recomiendo ampliamente leer la [documentación de seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/distributions.html) ya que ahi podras encontrar a mayor detalle el uso de las diferentes funciones orientadas a la visualización de datos.

Para unir una histograma y un kde lo puedes hacer pasando como parametro `kde=True` dentro de tu función `displot` del histograma.

Quedando de la siguiente manera.

```
sns.displot(x=age,kind=("hist"), kde=True)
```

Con lo cual podrás obtener una gráfica de salida similar a la siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]